# Django: Trying to get data form two views to show on one index page

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to display content from two different apps with two different views on my index page.

I made a views.py for my project to handle the index page and I'm trying to connect the model instances in my two apps to it. I'm not getting any errors, however I can't get anything to show other than the stuff in my base.html.

Here is the code along with the pictures to show what's happening vs. what I'm trying to do.

Project views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from colorsets.models import ColorSet
from adminpanel.models import Widget
from django.utils import timezone

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse,reverse_lazy

def home(request, template='index.html'):
    context = {
        'widget': ColorSet.objects.all(),
        'color_set': Widget.objects.all(),
        }
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Project urls.py:

```
"""colors URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.conf.urls import url, include
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include
from accounts import views
from colorsets import views
from colors import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$',views.home,name='index'),
    url(r'^accounts/',include('accounts.urls',namespace='accounts')),
    url(r'^colorsets/',include('colorsets.urls',namespace='colorsets')),
    url(r'^adminpanel/',include('adminpanel.urls',namespace='adminpanel')),
]
```

colorsets app urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from colorsets import views

app_name = 'colorsets'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^new/$',views.CreateColorSetView.as_view(),name='new_color'),
    url(r'delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.DeletePost.as_view(),name='delete'),
]
```

adminpanel urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from adminpanel import views

app_name = 'adminpanel'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^widgets/',views.SettingsListView.as_view(),name='widgets'),
    url(r'^new/$',views.CreateWidgetView.as_view(),name='create-widget'),
    url(r'^delete/$',views.DeleteWidget.as_view(),name='delete-widgets'),
]
```

Adminpanel app views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from adminpanel.forms import WidgetForm
from adminpanel.models import Widget
from django.utils import timezone

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse,reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from braces.views import SelectRelatedMixin
from django.views.generic import (TemplateView,ListView,
                                    DetailView,CreateView,
                                    UpdateView,DeleteView)

# Create your views here.
class CreateWidgetView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'index.html'
    form_class = WidgetForm
    model = Widget

    def form_valid(self,form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('adminpanel:widgets')

class SettingsListView(ListView):
    model = Widget
    ordering = ['widget_order']

class DeleteWidget(LoginRequiredMixin,SelectRelatedMixin,DeleteView):
    model = Widget
    select_related = ('Widget',)
    success_url = reverse_lazy('settings')

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_query()
        return queryset.filter(user_id=self.request.user.id)

    def delete(self):
        return super().delete(*args,**kwargs)
```

Colorset app views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from colorsets.forms import ColorForm
from colorsets import models
from colorsets.models import ColorSet
from django.utils import timezone

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse,reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from braces.views import SelectRelatedMixin
from django.views.generic import (TemplateView,ListView,
                                    DetailView,CreateView,
                                    UpdateView,DeleteView)

# Create your views here.
#def index(request):
#   return render(request,'index.html')

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = ColorSet

    def get_queryset(self):
        return ColorSet.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-published_date')

class CreateColorSetView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'index.html'
    form_class = ColorForm
    model = ColorSet

    def form_valid(self,form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

class DeletePost(LoginRequiredMixin,SelectRelatedMixin,DeleteView):
    model = models.ColorSet
    select_related = ('user',)
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(user_id=self.request.user.id)

    def delete(self,*args,**kwargs):
        return super().delete(*args,**kwargs)
```

index.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">
    {% include "adminpanel/widget_list" %}
    <div class="sidebar">

    </div>

    <div class="content">
    {% for colorset in colorset_list %}
            <div class="colorset-info">
                <h3 class="set-name">{{ colorset.name }}</h3>
                    <p class="author accent-text">Author: {{ colorset.user }}</p>

                    {% if user.is_authenticated and colorset.user == user %}
                        <a class="auth-user-options" href="{% url 'colorsets:delete' pk=colorset.pk %}">Delete</a>
                    {% endif %}
            </div>
            <table class="colorset">
                <tr>
                    <td class="color" style="background-color:#{{ colorset.color_one }}">
                    </td>
                    <td class="color" style="background-color:#{{ colorset.color_two }}">
                    </td>
                    <td class="color" style="background-color:#{{ colorset.color_three }}">
                    </td>
                    <td class="color" style="background-color:#{{ colorset.color_four }}">
                    </td>
                    <td class="color" style="background-color:#{{ colorset.color_five }}">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>#{{ colorset.color_one }}</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>#{{ colorset.color_two }}</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>#{{ colorset.color_three }}</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>#{{ colorset.color_four }}</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>#{{ colorset.color_five }}</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

widget_list.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="widgets-list">
        {% for widget in widget_list %}
            <h3>{{ widget.name }}</h3>
            <h3>{{ widget.widget_order }}</h3>
            <div>
                <p>{{ widget.body }}</p>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <a class="#" href="{% url 'adminpanel:create-widget' %}">New Widget</a>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Here is what I want to happen on index.html:
[image]

Here is what is actually happening:
[image]

Comment: Your `for` loop in `index.html` is iterating over `colorset_list` but your context only has `color_set` and `widget` (that context looks backwards by the way: `widget`->`Colorset` while `color_set`->`Widget`).

Comment: @FamousJameous Got it working, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the views.py assign the wrong context names, just swap them.

Second there is a problem in how you built your templates:

The index.html include the `widget_list` (without ".html"!) this code define the content of `block content`. And is already called in a block content.

In my opinion you should create a `widget_list_inner.html` that contains only the code you want to reuse in other parts of the application.

The new `widget_list.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        {% include "adminpanel/widget_list_inner.html" %}
        <a class="#" href="{% url 'adminpanel:create-widget' %}">New Widget</a>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

widget_list_inner.html

```
  <div class="widgets-list">
    {% for widget in widget_list %}
        <h3>{{ widget.name }}</h3>
        <h3>{{ widget.widget_order }}</h3>
        <div>
           <p>{{ widget.body }}</p>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

Now you can include in your index.html the `widget_list_inner` in any place of the index.html

Apply the same thing for the color_set.html. Yes, move the code out from the `index.html`. Take a look at the documentation of the include: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#include

As you can see you can pass context values to your include, this is helpful to reuse the `*_inner.html` templates everywhere in your app.

Comment: Tried that and switched a couple other things and it worked, thank you.